# How to parse Restfull api JSON response in retrofit?

Tags: android, api, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a typical Retrofit API request. I have used a vb.net API call and it returns the response as bellow.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> {"UserTickets":[{"Type":"Application","Category":"Mobile App","Sub Category":"Other","Issue Details":"Dummy","LMDT":"2019-11-14 15:46:00.000","ResponsibleEmail":"alex@goba.com"}],"success":"true","status:":"1"}</string>
```

I can't able to get a response body using the below code. How can I fetch a response-body from the response object? May anyone help me?. API Call Android Code as bellow:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

CryptocurrencyService scalarService = mRetrofit.create(CryptocurrencyService.class);
            Call<String> stringCall = scalarService.getStringResponse("800028");
            stringCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String responseString = response.body().toString();
                        // todo: do something with the response string
                        Log.e("TAG_RESPONSE", responseString);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your response is not JSON, that's why you are not able to get the response.

Instead, if your response is a plain string you should add a Retrofit scalar converter `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0` , you can see an example [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-receive-plain-string-responses).

Or if you want to handle the response as a XML you should add this converter `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jaxb:2.4.0`